# Can't click next page button while scraping Tripadvisor with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to scrape the list of all restaurants in Tripadvisor and list all results, but I can't find the way to click the next button neither with css selector nor with xpath
This is what I used

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import pandas
import json
import pprint
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g187849-Milan_Lombardy.html")
button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[5]/div[3]/div/a')
button.click()
list_restaurants = (wd.find_elements_by_class_name("div._2Q7zqOgW"))
print(len(list_restaurants))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to scroll all the way down till `botton`, to let Selenium know where is the next button, also there are trailing spaces so `LINK_TEXT` won't work, instead try with `Partial_link_text`

**Code :-**

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(50)
wd.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g187849-Milan_Lombardy.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)
time.sleep(5)
print(wd.title)

wd.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
time.sleep(5)
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Next")))
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ele)
print('done')
```

and then, You can continue with rest of your scripts.

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g187849-Milan_Lombardy.html")
for i in range(5): #Click on next for 5 times.
    time.sleep(2) # Need time to load the page.
    res = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-test-target='restaurants-list']//div[@class='wQjYiB7z']//a")
    print(len(res)) # Prints 37 for 5 times.
    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",next)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-100);") # Scroll back so that the Next option is visible.
    next.click()

driver.quit()
```